# Jquery implementation in struts2

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am new to struts2.I have to use jQuery in my struts2.so how should I implement jQuery? What are the jars,js files are needed to call jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

It is a JavaScript library, you can embed from Google hosted library or download from jquery.com

Use from

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Download from http://jquery.com/